# Sublime Snippets break with left-square brackets

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Given the following `test.sublime-snippet`

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[//test replacement
//${1}
//${1/(.*)/<$1>/g}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>test</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Install it. Trigger it with `test`<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Enter some text and you'll see replacement stops when you enter the left square bracket <kbd>[</kbd> key. Sublime correctly auto-places the other bracket <kbd>]</kbd> though it should continue to match.

Is this a bug or am I missing a special escape character?

Here is the buggy snippet I'm trying to fix: [Go Class snippet](https://gist.github.com/jpillora/46e378826f8f2e4d68a6)

Comment: Can you post what your desired outcome of this snippet should be.  It seems it fails for all brackets that are set to automatch, not just the `[` bracket.

Comment: I'm doing something even more complex with regard, this is just a simple example of the bug. The only problem I'm having is I need to use auto match characters in snippets.

Comment: Edit: regex* not regard (iPhone auto-correct). Added link to snippet I'm trying to fix.

Comment: If you temporarily disable the 'auto_match_enabled' setting, you'll see that sublime is able to continue the snippet replacement even if ou enter a left bracket ([). So, it seems like the problem is that the auto match tag throws out sublime from snippet context to other context.

Comment: @sergioFC Thanks for the tip. Looks like I'll have to write a plugin to do what I need...

Comment: I guess you already know it, but I have just noticed that simple snippets keeps working even if that setting is enabled and you introduce a tag. So, I don't know what is the real problem. Simple snippet: <content><![CDATA[
//${1}
//${1}
//${2}
]]></content>

Comment: It seems that it's only with regex placeholders

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Sublime Text, whereby, when the `insert_snippet` command is executed when typing <kbd>[</kbd> for example, when `auto_match_enabled` is set to true, it causes ST to lose the information about the regex substitution for the snippet you were originally typing in.

It has been logged as an issue here:
https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1017

the only workaround at the moment would be to implement the same `auto_match_enabled` functionality without using the `insert_snippet` command.